# How to print char from DL (or similar) in assembly? (intel syntax 32bit)

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, intel-syntax

At the beginning, I'd like to point out that I'm totally newbie in assembly. I have to make a program that get from command line 2 arguments - int and string. Next, it has to print in console last word from string as many times as int number says. 
I'm using Intel syntax in 32-bit - that's important I guess.

For example: ./a.out 3 "ab cd" shows on the screen "cdcdcd"

First, I focus just on finding last word and printing it on the screen - not in the loop but just once. Adding a loop shouldn't be a big problem for me. I tried my best to write working code and it compiled without errors but it doesn't print anything in console - I think that there's a mistake in printing "char by char" from the last word. I have no idea how to print it correctly. I'd be so grateful for help. I am limited to the little knowledge acquired at university so please let all your tips are as simple as possible that I could understand them. :)

```
 .intel_syntax noprefix

.globl main
.text

main:
 push ebp
 mov ebp, esp       
 mov ebx, [ebp + 12]
 mov ecx, [ebx + 4] # int ECX
 mov ebx, [ebx + 8] # string EBX
 xor eax, eax 

 call findend

 pop ebp
 mov ebx, 0
 mov ecx, 0
 ret

findend:
 mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax]
 cmp dl, 0
 jz findword
 inc eax
 jmp findend

findword: 
 dec eax
 mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax]
 cmp dl, ' '
 jz foundword
 jmp findword

foundword:
 inc eax
 mov dl, byte ptr [ebx + eax]
 cmp dl, 0
 jz theend
 push eax
 push edx
 push offset msg1
 call printf
 add esp, 4
 pop edx
 pop eax
 jmp foundword

theend:
 ret


.data
 msg1:   .asciz "%c"
```

Comment: `cmp dl, '0'` should be `cmp dl, 0`.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a stupid mistake... I edited my post but now it just loops without showing anything...

Comment: Also note that `call printf` will destroy `eax`

Comment: You can simplify your design if you let `printf` print the last word at once. Just remember the position of the last space while scanning the input string for the null term. Then invoke `printf` with that address the number of times required. This assumes well-formatted input. The best advice is investing in a debugger, though.

Comment: Ok, I edited my code and know I think it saves eax content by pushing it and poping back after printf. Currently it shows first letter of the last string and others are replaced by "�". What's wrong now?...

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for replying. I know what you mean but I don't really know how can my assembly program know which space is the last space?

Comment: You don't want to push/pop 16 bit even if your assembler accepts that. `pop msg1` shouldn't even assemble. You had it correct earlier, just switch back to the `add esp, 8` (of course keep the `push/pop eax`).

Comment: You still didn't fix the very first thing I told you to. With that, it works fine here.

Comment: I know, I just forgot to edit my post. Big thanks for help, now it works - I have just to add a loop that will repeat the last word. I also tried version with "pop msg1, pop edx" instead of "add esp, 8". It seems like there's an error with popping msg1 because when I compile with just "pop edx" and "add esp, 4" the program still works. It's not necessary because I know what's the working solution  but I wonder why does it work like that and maybe you can explain why :)

Comment: `pop msg1` should not even assemble as `msg1` is an address you can't pop into it. All you care about is preserving `eax` and maintaining stack balance, thus you can just discard the pushed arguments with `add esp,8`or popping into wherever you want.

Comment: *"how can my assembly program know which space is the last space?"* reserve one register to keep "address of last space+1" (init it with the start of input address, so in case input is "nospace", it will point at "n"). Then scan the string char by char, whenever you find space ' ', update that register with new address (the address of ' ' + 1). Scan until end of string (`0`). At end of string that register contains address of first letter of last word in input string (In case of "spaceAfter " input string it will point at the terminating `0`).